# Common-mode voltage on the body

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, resistors, common-mode

In the attached figure, input impedances of the right hand, right leg and left hand are respectively \$20k,50k\$ and \$10k\$ Ohms. The input impedance of the opamp is also assumed to be \$1M\, \Omega\$. Power line induces a displacement current of \$100\$ nA into the body.

**Problem:** What is the ratio of common-mode voltage on the body when the right legged is ungrounded with respect to when it is gorunded?

[image]

**Attempt to solve:**

In the first case when the right leg is ungrounded, the current has to go through the left hand, the opamp and the right hand. However the common-mode voltage is assumed to be equal throughout the entire body (?), so the left and right hands form a closed loop:
$$ V_L - V_R = 10^{-7}\times (10^6 + 3\times 10^4) = 0.1 + 0.003  \approx0.1V. $$

In the second case when the leg is grounded, all the resistors short-circuit and the current goes directly into the right leg:
$$V_{leg} = 10^{-7}\times 5\times 10^4 = 0.005V.$$
The ratio thus is \$0.1/0.005=20\$. However my solution manual says \$10\$ is the correct answer. I'd be grateful if you could help me figure out why.

This is also my first question on EE site, so forgive me if I'm a noob!

Comment: 1) It is unclear how that stick figure (your body?) behaves electrically so it is impossible to say what happens. 2) Usually opamps are assumed to draw no current from their inputs so no current would flow through the 10 kohm and 20 kohm resistors. If your opamp does draw a current then explicitly mention that. 3) The drawing might become easier if you replaced the opamp with a voltmeter. 4) Why is one resistor 10 k and the other 20 k ?

Comment: 1) Consider the body simply as wire, it conveys current whenever the wire is connected to circuit. 2) I think that's when the input resistance is infinity. But here the statement of the problem says it's 1M Ohms. 3&4) Again, this was the statement of the problem. Maybe different electrodes with different source impedances are connected to the hands?